# Star Wars Rebels - getting rid of Minister Tua

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

Today I began to wonder when Tarkin, Darth Vader, and Agent Kallus started planning to get rid of Minister Tua.

Did Tarkin have the Inquisitor behead the two failed officers in front of her to put a scare into her, so that she could later be  frightened into contacting the rebels for help by ordering her to report to Tarkin about her failure to catch the Lothal rebels?

Or did Darth Vader and Agent Kallus later come up with that plan on their own as a way to attract the rebels and replace a "soft" official?  Was the beheading in front of her just something which made them think she might be frightened enough to defect to the rebels?

Either way is not very good for recruiting to the Imperial service.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. What do any of two options have to do with recruiting to the Imperial service?

Comment: Andres F. - If it became known that even such a senior official could be murdered as part of a plot to destroy rebels that would make people considering joining the imperial services wonder how many decades they might have to serve before finally not being considered disposable.  And most of them would realize that they would probably never reach such a high position that they would be safe from being casually murdered by other officials.

Comment: But such a plot to destroy the rebels would be a secret, wouldn't it? It's not a recruitment campaign, it's a secret plot! The common people are not supposed to know what happens in Imperial mid/upper management.

Comment: Andres F - Yes, but the crew of the Ghost don't like being accused of murdering Minister Tua and may try to clear their names.  And suppose that the public hears their story and tends to believe it?  In many societies a large part of the public is very cynical about the official government story and willing to believe alternate claims - thus there are many conspiracy theories which are believed by many Americans despite or because of being discreditable to the government.

Comment: Since the goal of the Empire was never to *recruit* the crew of the Ghost, I don't see why it's a problem if the rebels don't like the accusation. *Obviously*, had the plan succeeded, they would have been killed. The public was supposed to turn them in, not to "hear their story". This being a cartoon, things don't go that well for the villains... why is this a surprise? :)

Answer (score 2):

I just watched the episode. It seems to be a plan devised by Darth Vader and (possibly) Agent Kallus, not by Tarkin. However, it's likely Tarkin's brutal methods shown earlier in season 1 helped make Minister Tua's mind.

> "Everything has happened as you predicted, Lord Vader."
>
> ~ Agent Kallus

and

> "A beloved citizen of Lothal, Minister Tua's life was cut short by this criminal band of rebels [picture]. If you see them, summon Imperial authorities immediately."
>
> ~ Imperial public announcement following the murder of Tua.

and

> They did this to turn Lothal against us. We can't do any more here. We have to leave, for good.
>
> ~ Hera

This seems clear-cut. Vader thought of a plan to murder Tua (a "soft" public official, like you said) while making it look as if the murderers were the rebels. This had the multiple goal of flushing out the rebels, turning the population against them, and of course:

> there was a tracking device in the stolen Imperial shuttle. Finding and destroying the Rebel fleet was ultimately the goal of the whole plan, not merely the events on Lothal.

This plan wouldn't have a negative impact on Imperial recruitment if it had succeeded, and if fact it would have probably bolstered it. "Join the Stormtrooper Corps, fight the insurgent assassins!"

Comment: As I said, it could have a negative effect if a large part of the public came to believe whatever public denial the crew of the Ghost made.  And I rather suspect that a large part of the population was more cynical than naive about the intentions of the empire.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Had the plan succeeded, it wouldn't have had any negative effect. The crew of the Ghost are insurgents and alleged assassins, so why would the general population believe them? Why would they believe the Empire would be willing to murder their own officials in cold blood? Note *even Agent Kallus* is surprised by the murder of the two incompetent Imperial officers in another episode, so why would the common people even believe the Empire is capable of this?